# How to get url values and push to array in PHP

Tags: php, url, php-7.1

I have one url,from there I am passing one parameter two values,Now my question is,I want take the values push in to array how can do this?

**MY URL**

```
http://localhost/TransitoakAdmin/licenseUpload.php?uploadfile=file1.docx&file2.pdf
```

**I want make like this**

```
$fileNames=array('files/file1.docx','files/file2.pdf');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following code ;

```
$url = "http://localhost/TransitoakAdmin/licenseUpload.php?uploadfile=file1.docx&file2.pdf";
$urlstrip = explode('uploadfile=',$url);
$fileNames = explode('&',$urlstrip[1]);

foreach ( $fileNames as $key=> $fileName ){
    $fileNames[$key] = 'file/'.$fileName;
}

var_dump($fileNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_GET` to retrieve values from URL parameters and `explode` to split a string by string.

> website.com/uploadFile=file1.docx,file2.docx

```
$param = htmlspecialchars($_GET['uploadFile']);
$files = explode(',', $param); // outputs ['file1.docx', 'file2.docx']

array_map(function($val) {
    return 'files/' . $val; // prepend 'files/' string to each entry
}, $files);
```